# Error Code 1064 for BEGIN Try

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I need someone help trying to figure out why this BEGIN TRY is throwing me an error?

```
use my_guitar_shop;
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS update_product_discount; 
DELIMITER $$ 
CREATE PROCEDURE update_product_discount
( 
    IN product_id INT, 
    IN discount_percent INT
)
BEGIN  
    BEGIN TRY
        UPDATE products
        SET discount_percent = discount_percent
        WHERE product_id = product_id
    END TRY;
END;
BEGIN CATCH
    IF discount_percent < 0 THEN
        SELECT 'The discount percent must be positive' AS message 
END CATCH;
END $$


DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Don't name your in variables the same as the column names in the table.  DB Engine is  getting confused to if you mean the parameter passed in or the column of the table.  a good convention is P_IN_FieldName or P_OUT_Fieldname so you know if it's a in or output parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You should test discount_percent before you try the update. Unless there's a problem with the update, it won't fail and see the catch.

Also, don't use the same names for variables as column names.

```
use my_guitar_shop;
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS update_product_discount; 
DELIMITER $$ 
CREATE PROCEDURE update_product_discount
( 
    IN this_product_id INT, 
    IN new_discount_percent INT
)
BEGIN
    IF discount_percent < 0 THEN
        BEGIN
            SELECT 'The discount percent must be positive' AS message;
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN  
            BEGIN TRY
                UPDATE products
                SET discount_percent = new_discount_percent
                WHERE product_id = this_product_id;
            END TRY
            BEGIN CATCH
                SELECT 'An error occured while saving.' AS message;
            END CATCH
        END
    END
END
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: So I added your code in. I'm getting a syntax error on END after the AS message. I'm still getting the TRY syntax error and now it's giving me a CATCH syntax error.

Comment: There were a couple of missing semicolons. See updated answer.

Comment: Thank you for helping me. Unfortunately, the fix that you put up still has the syntax error. The error that I'm still getting is BEGIN TRY AND END TRY. For some reason, the END under the END CATCH is asking for an END IF.

Comment: CREATE PROCEDURE update_product_discount (IN this_product_id INT, IN new_discount_percent INT ) IF discount_percent < 0 THEN     BEGIN SELECT 'The discount percent must be positive' AS message;     END ELSE BEGIN BEGIN TRY UPDATE products SET discount_percent = new_discount_percent WHERE product_id = this_product_id;         END TRY         BEGIN CATCH             SELECT 'An error occured while saving.' AS message;         END CATCH     END END Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; near 'ELSE     BEGIN BEGIN TRY UPDATE products   SET d' at line 10

Comment: Seems there is a missing begin at the start of the procedure.

Comment: I fixed it. Thank you again for the help. I just got rid of the TRY and CATCH all together.